# how to convert dbf to csv?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, dbf

How to convert a DBF to CSV?
I need, use this library but it gave error: http://pythonhosted.org/dbf

```
import dbf

dbf.export('crop1-fx')
print 'Done'
```

> "C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\python.exe"
>   "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/23/dbf/insertValuesDBF.py" Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/23/dbf/insertValuesDBF.py", line 3, in
>   
>       dbf.export('crop1-fx')   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_2.py", line 7824,
>   in export
>       table = source_table(table_or_records[0])   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_2.py", line 7956,
>   in source_table
>       table = thingie._meta.table() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
import dbf

db = dbf.Table('crop1-fx')
dbf.export(db)
```

The above will create a `crop1-fx.csv` file; however, I'm not sure this will work with a 24-digit numeric field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `.DBF` file to `.CSV`, download dBASE III PLUS or any other dBASE
software available on NET. Please note I am referring to 16 bit platform on
DOS.

Once dBASE is downloaded, go to the DOT prompt and give the following commands:

Type

```
use   <the dbf file in question without the extension .dbf>
```

You will see the name of the dbf file on the display bar

Then, type "copy to" <file name you want, limited to 8 characters>

"delimited"

Now the data in the dbf file is sent to a TEXT file with data in each field surrounded by `" "` (double inverted commas)  and separated by `,` (comma)

Now this file can be used to export the data to any other DATABASE SYSTEM which has got provision to convert this `.CSV` or DELIMITED FILE  to the new database.

If only comma-separated file without the " " marks are required a procedure
can be written in dBASE to achieve that also.